# cURL Error #:Unknown cipher in list: tls_ecdhe_rsa_with_aes_256_cbc_sha

Tags: php, linux, curl

I have received this error when I execute code:

> cURL Error #:Unknown cipher in list: tls_ecdhe_rsa_with_aes_256_cbc_sha

**curl version:7.56.1**

```
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'tls_ecdhe_rsa_with_aes_256_cbc_sha');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 $xml = curl_exec($ch);
 $err = curl_error($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 $xmls = trim($xml);
 echo $xmls;
 echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
```

How to solve this problem? And how to add or enable cipher `tls_ecdhe_rsa_with_aes_256_cbc_sha`?

Comment: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/ssl-ciphers.html may help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP curl: "Unknown cipher in list"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24991239/php-curl-unknown-cipher-in-list)